# Move/rename directory with git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My company uses SVN repository but I would like to use Git. At the moment I'm using git-svn, but when I move or rename a directory with a several of files in Git and "git svn dcommit" such change, in SVN repository this results into individual files moves:

```
Changed paths:
  D /directory/file1
  D /directory/file2
  D /directory/file3
  D /directory/file4
  ...
  A /renamedDirectory
  A /renamedDirectory/file1 (from /directory/file1:67918)
  A /renamedDirectory/file2 (from /directory/file2:67918)
  A /renamedDirectory/file3 (from /directory/file3:67918)
  A /renamedDirectory/file4 (from /directory/file4:67918)
  ....
```

Instead I would expect to see something like that:

```
Changed paths:
  D /directory
  A /renamedDirectory (from /directory:67918)
```

i.e. full directory rename. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: For fancy stuff like this, I'd use svn client (even if only for this operation).

Comment: I would suggest using git-svn for most work, but for Subversion-specific functionality like this, just do whatever you need to do using svn directly. Problem solved.

Comment: Please note that in some respects git and svn are quite different. Be prepared to know how each of the tools do things and to use the right tool in the right circumstance. If you're unprepared for this I would stick with svn to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

When renaming (moving) directories in git, it's **only the files** that git moves, not the directory.

If I'm renaming a folder called `pdfs` to `pdfs2`

```
$ git mv pdfs pdfs2

$ git status

renamed:    pdfs/filea -> pdfs2/filea
renamed:    pdfs/fileb -> pdfs2/fileb
```

So I think this how git works, and so git-svn works that way, too.

There isn't a way for git to say "I am 100% sure that this is a full directory move operation" and therefore translate this to SVN as a directory move. Git only knows/cares about the files.

---

Also: You'll notice that if you try commit an empty directory git will complain:

```
$ mkdir afolder
$ git add afolder && git commit -m "Added afolder"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This is again because git doesn't care about directories, just files.

Answer (score 2):

There is a major difference between SVN and Git when it comes to file moves and copies:

- Subversion keeps *copy-from* metadata of every copy operation performed in repository.
- Git does not keep this kind of metadata, it rather relies on certain heuristics in order to determine whether files or directories were copied or moved.

Different Git commands use different rename detection techniques, e.g. `git log --stat -M` does detect directory renames:

```
git log --stat -M
...
{directory => renamedDirectory}/file1 
{directory => renamedDirectory}/file2
{directory => renamedDirectory}/file3
{directory => renamedDirectory}/file4
```

However, `git-svn` does not try to detect renamed directories when sending your Git commits to SVN repository, hence, *copy-from* metadata generated by `git-svn` does not reflect directory rename which you'd expect, it renames individual files in corresponding revision instead.

We took a different approach in [SubGit](http://subgit.com) which is an alternative to `git-svn`: when one moves a directory with Git:

```
$ git mv directory renamedDirectory
```

and then pushes this change to SubGit-enabled Git repository:

```
$ git commit -m 'Rename directory to renamedDirectory'
$ git push
```

SubGit does convert this change as a directory rename in Subversion repository:

```
Changed paths:
  D /directory
  A /renamedDirectory (from /directory:123)
```

You may consider trying SubGit if you find it important to preserve this kind of metadata in Subversion repository. Here's a [quick start guide](http://subgit.com/howto.html).